# Docker CE and Windows Server compatibility?

Tags: docker

Taken from https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/:

> System Requirements:
>
> - Windows 10 64bit: Pro, Enterprise or Education (Build 15063 or later).
> - Virtualization is enabled in BIOS. Typically, virtualization is enabled by default. This is different from having Hyper-V enabled. For
>     more detail see [Virtualization must be
>     enabled](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#virtualization-must-be-enabled)
>     in Troubleshooting.
> - CPU SLAT-capable feature.
> - At least 4GB of RAM.

As you see, it doesn't state which Windows Server versions are compatible. Does anyone know?

States here https://success.docker.com/article/compatibility-matrix however it does not state the CE edition.

Answer (score -1):

This [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions) tells you all windows server versions.

And from [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/quick-start-windows-server), all microsoft documentation about windows container focus on `Windows Server 2019` and `Windows Server 2016`.

And docker project starts from the year 2013, so the latest old version  `Windows Server 2012` (Not include 2016, 2019) I guess not support docker as kernel need to support that.